# Need help with regex to convert BBCode tags to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a Javascript regex.

```
/\[([^:]*)\]/gi
```

Basically what it needs to do is to get content of [ ] and place it inside of HTML tag src. Like bbForums do.

Problem is when i have input as [somescr] i get proper results but when i have more than one [somesrc] [someothersrc] in row, Regex matches everything between first and last brackets ( ie. somesrc] [someothersrc )

Can you help me with it?

thanks

Comment: Try a better post title (something more along the lines of "regex matching too much"). There are already too many questions entitled "need help with regex".

Comment: Chris, if i knew English or to express myself at any spoken language i wouldn't be a developer but a teacher. This is the beauty of this community that you can search google and even if your question is messed up gibberish you would find an answer.

Comment: that still doesn't entirely excuse you from trying to come up with an interesting question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `/\[([^:]*?)\]/gi`

For more info, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-does-lazy-and-greedy-means-in-regexp).

Comment: You'd need to escape those brackets, by the way.

Comment: @SteveWang: They are, they didn't show up in unformatted code.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a lazy quantifier. So replace `*` with `*?`, and it should work magically.

Comment: thanks for quick answer but Aziz got less StackoverFlow mojo, hence you got +1 and he got the answer with your help of course.... Sorry for being a communist

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern: `\[([^:]*?)\]`. Put `?` after `*` to make it lazy.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
myString.replace(/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[/\1\]/gi, "<$1>$2</$1>")
```